# Kafka Connect/Landoop: A Recursive Path for FtpSourceConfig

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka connect with the kafka-connect-ftp plugin by Landoop (https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/source/ftp.html .)

Is there a way to use `connect.ftp.monitor.tail` with a recursive path definition, in order to track all files in a directory recursively?

I've tried to do something like

```
connect.ftp.monitor.tail=/**:topic-name
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the code only supports single star glob patterns, and matches on filenames, not directories

https://github.com/Landoop/stream-reactor/blob/master/kafka-connect-ftp/src/main/scala/com/datamountaineer/streamreactor/connect/ftp/source/FtpFileLister.scala#L41

Sounds like a good idea for a github issue, though